# In python BeautifulSoup4, convert string into arguments for find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a simple Python script that uses BeautifulSoup to find a section of the HTML tree. For example, to find everything inside the `<div id="doctext">` tags, the script does this:

```
html_section = str(soup.find("div", id="doctext"))
```

I would like to be able to make the arguments to `find()` vary, however, according to strings given in an input file. For example, a user could feed the script a URL followed by a string like `"div", id="doctext"`, and the script would adjust the find accordingly. Imagine that the input file looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com | "div", id="doctext"
```

The script splits the line to get the URL, which works fine, but I want it to also grab the arguments. For example:

```
vars = line.split(' | ')
html = urllib2.urlopen(vars[0]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
args = vars[1].split()
html_section = str(soup.find(*args))
```

This doesn't work---and probably doesn't make sense as I've been trying multiple ways to do this. How do I get the string provided by the input file and prepare it into the right syntax for the `soup.find()` function?

Comment: what is the error do you get?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. See my comment on @unutbu's answer. When I do `soup.find("div", id="doctext")`, I get the HTML I want, but when I try to get the arguments from `line` somehow, BeautifulSoup returns `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse `line` like this:

```
line = 'http://www.example.com | div, id=doctext'
url, args = line.split(' | ', 1)
args = args.split(',')
name = args[0]
params = dict([param.strip().split('=') for param in args[1:]])
print(name)
print(params)
```

yields

```
div
{'id': 'doctext'}
```

Then you could call `soup.find` like this:

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
html_section = str(soup.find(name, **params))
```

---

WARNING: Note that if `doctext` (or some other keyword argument) contains a comma, then

```
args = args.split(',')
```

will split the parameters in the wrong place. This problem might arise if you are searching for some `text` content that contains a comma.

---

**So let's look for a better solution:**

To avoid the problem described above, you might consider using the [JSON format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for the arguments: if `line` looks like this:

```
'http://www.example.com | ["div", {"id": "doctext"}]'
```

Then you could parse it with

```
import json
line = 'http://www.example.com | ["div", {"id": "doctext"}]'
url, arguments = line.split('|', 1)
url = url.strip()
arguments = json.loads(arguments)
args = []
params = {}
for item in arguments:
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        params = item
    else:
        args.append(item)

print(args)
print(params)
```

which yields

```
[u'div']
{u'id': u'doctext'}
```

Then you could call `soup.find` with

```
html_section = str(soup.find(*args, **params))
```

An added advantage is that you can supply any number of [soup.find's positional arguments](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) (for `name`, `attrs`, `recursive`, and `text`), not just the `name`.

Comment: +1 for a nicer input format.  The best I could think of  was something like `url, sep, option_str = line.partition(" | "); grouped = itertools.groupby(shlex.shlex(option_str), lambda w: w != ','); params = [''.join(g) for k,g in grouped if k]` to get reasonable don't-split-inside-quotes behaviour.

Comment: The first solution doesn't work. `soup.find(name, **params)` returns `None`, even though `soup.find("div", id="doctext")` returns the HTML I'm looking for. Haven't tried the JSON yet, but wonder if this sheds more light on the problem.

Comment: @CalebMcDaniel: There were too many quotation marks in `name`. We could add code to strip them out, or change the format for `line`. I corrected the post using fewer quotes in `line`. However, I really think the JSON solution is a better way to go.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

assume that user will feed the script those args, you will get them with
sys.argv, then use them with your code

```
#foo.py
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg

hvn@hvnatvcc: ~/test $ python foo.py http://xyz.com div doctext
foo.py
http://xyz.com
div
doctext
```

your code will look like this

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(sys.argv[1]).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
html_section = str(soup.find(sys.argv[2], id=sys.argv[3]))
```

what wrong with your code is:
 `find()` will not treat `id` in string `id="doctext"` as a keywork of function. Python see `'id="doctext"'` as a whole string.